# GUID to open Geoprocessing Enviroment Settings Window through C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am trying to let the user click the enviroment button at the bottom of my custom form and have the Enviroment Window Pop Up. I cannot seem to locate the Enviroment Settings Window GUID anywhere?

```
    void environmentsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        UID uid = new UIDClass();

        uid.Value = "esriGeoprocessing.GPEnviromentSettingsWindow";
        Debug.WriteLine("Setting");
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IDockableWindow win = Program.ActiveDockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(uid);
        Debug.WriteLine("Showing");
        win.Show(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_cpp/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000012q000000 and search for esriGeoprocessingUI.GPEnvironmentsCmd, that looks more like what you're after. It comes from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\esriGeoprocessingUI.GPEnvironmentsCmd as an ICommandItem with ICommandBars.Find then execute the commanditem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the old edn page containing a list of commands and their GUID is always frustrating.

I recall about one year ago, I created a tool to intercept the GUID of all ArcGIS commands, once they are executed. `ArcGIS UID Intercepter` can be downloaded from [GitHub page](https://github.com/faridcher/ArcUIDIntercepter).

By taking advantage of that tool, the GUID for `Environment Settings Windows` would be:

```
{67EFF682-3AAB-4301-B7F6-46A4178FC923}
```

And remember that this window (evn setting) is not a dockable window and the proper way to open it is by using this snippet:

```cs
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = mapplication.Document.CommandBars;
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
uid.Value = "{67EFF682-3AAB-4301-B7F6-46A4178FC923}"
ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid, false, false);
if (commandItem != null)
    commandItem.Execute();
```